# Why inline <script> tag doesn't show the value?

Tags: jquery, html

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7T6W.png)I need to convert value received by the server (bytes to MB). Only option I have is to embed script tag and run the jquery function that converts that value. Problem is that inline script doesn't return any value to html.

```
function formatFileSize(bytes) {
    if (bytes == 0) return '0 Byte';
    return (bytes / Math.pow(1024, 2)).toFixed(2);
 }
```

Html code

```
 <td>
    <script>
         formatFileSize(DailyUsage.UsageVolume)
    </script>
</td>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'return any value to HTML'? That's not how JS works in general, you would need to write the code to do that. Where is this function called from, and what do you do with the response? Where in your HTML are you expecting the value to be displayed?

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. You can solve this by using `document.write()`, but you should really avoid using it as it's not good practice. Is it possible you can output the `DailyUsage.UsageVolume` value to a data attribute on the `td` itself? That way you can easily update the text within the cell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because nothing is outputting it to the token stream. All your function does is *return* the value, but nothing makes use of the value it returns.

You could output it using `document.write`, which will insert that output betweeen the `<td>` and `</td>` when the page is loaded:

```
<td>
    <script>
         document.write(formatFileSize(DailyUsage.UsageVolume))
    </script>
</td>
```

...but usually there are better approaches to outputting information than putting lots of inline `script` tags with `document.write` in them, and note that you'd have to have an in-scope variable called `DailyUsage` referencing an object with a `UsageVolume` property for that to work.

Comment: Umm ,you should write to particular element?? why whole document?

Comment: @Shubh - I don't understand your question.

Comment: @integrater - Glad that helped! You might look into using a templating engine, or (depending on how complex your use case is) an MVC framework.

Comment: Well i was confused about document.write thing ,like you should select the particular dom element to write the output. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @Shubh - `document.write` does not replace all the document's inner content when executed while it is loading, it writes within the document stream.

Comment: Yeah I got that ,after research @KévinBibollet

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<div id="result"></div> <script>
```

```js
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHtml = formatFileSize(DailyUsage.UsageVolume);
}
```

```html
</script>
```

You firstly need to have a html element and then to point the result of the function to this HTML

Answer (score -1):

You can do as follows

```
<td id="content">
</td>


 <script>
     function formatFileSize(bytes) {
       if (bytes == 0) return '0 Byte';
          return (bytes / Math.pow(1024, 2)).toFixed(2);
      }
     document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = formatFileSize(DailyUsage.UsageVolume);
 </script>
```